# Java WebStart : Why does the application volume not adjust to the system volume

Tags: java, audio, volume, java-web-start

I've got a Java WebStart application which has an audio player in it that plays music. When testing the application (not running WebStart) the volume can be adjusted by adjusting the system volume.

However, when running the application via Java WebStart, somehow the application volume absolutely ignores the system volume. Regardless of how much I adjust, or even mute, the system volume, the application volume is unaffected.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how i can troubleshoot this issue? It seems to be WebStart related somehow?

**UPDATE:**

This seems to be an Ubuntu or Linux specific issue. The application respects the system volume on Windows and Mac OS, but not on Linux.

Comment: Why are you trying to manipulate the system volume in order to affect the volume of your app.?  BTW - I have written a music player launched by webstart, it has it's own volume setting but will still respect (or is a slave to - depending on how you want to look at it) the system volume.

Comment: @Andrew, i can't be bothered to implement a volume button in the application, so I'd like the application volume to "reflect" the system volume. However, audio plays at really high volume and adjusting system volume (by clicking on the volume icon in,say, windows) does not have any affect on the application volume.

Comment: So ..your code is..?  Your point is..?  BTW - just glanced at the edit.  Please inform commentators when the question is edited.  I have not tried my app. recently on Linux, don't have access to Mac.

Comment: @Andrew, I don't believe it is my specific code which is the problem. I've tried out Java Webstart demos of JavaZoom's MP3 player and that has the same problem. Volume is set to max when music is played via the Java Webstart application, and if i go to the system volume controls and adjust the volume there the java application is unaffected by the change. In other words, the java application is totally ignorant to all changes to the system volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this problem, somehow, was related to the combination of a docking station I'm using and Ubuntu. I can't explain why it occured, but I can't be bothered as long as the problem is that specific.